# Trouble adding numbers together in python

Tags: python

I am trying to rum a program that simulates 5 dice rolls. I know there is something simple I am missing, but I can't put a finger on it. I have tried to change the dice roll int, but it only prints the number in the output nothing is being added. What have I done??? The code is here and the output is below. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
# This program will simulate dice rolls 5 different
# times and add the total of each roll.

import random
MIN = 1
MAX = 6
ROLLS = 5
def main():
    print(random.randint(MIN, MAX))
    print(random.randint(MIN, MAX))

    for count in range(ROLLS):
        if random.randint(MIN,MAX)== 2:
            print('The total is two!')
        elif random.randint(MIN,MAX)== 3:
            print('The total is three!')
        elif random.randint(MIN,MAX) == 4:
            print('The total is four!')
        elif random.randint(MIN,MAX) == 5:
            print('The total is five!')
        elif random.randint(MIN,MAX) == 6:
            print('The total is six!')
        elif random.randint(MIN,MAX) == 7:
            print('The total is seven!')
        elif random.randint(MIN,MAX) == 8:
            print('The total is eight!')
        elif random.randint(MIN,MAX) == 9:
            print('The total is nine!')
        elif random.randint(MIN,MAX) == 10:
            print('The total is ten!')
        elif random.randint(MIN,MAX) == 11:
            print('The total is eleven!')
        else:
            print('The total is twelve!')





        print('The dice will be rolled and the total shown')
        print('each time enter is pressed up to five times!')

        total = point(MIN, MAX)
        print('The total is', total)




def point(MIN, MAX):
    for count in range(MIN, MAX):

        dicerolls = 0.0
        total = 0.0
        dice = input('')
        total += dicerolls

        return total 



main()
2
2
The total is twelve!
The dice will be rolled and the total shown
each time enter is pressed up to five times!

The total is 0.0
The total is three!
The dice will be rolled and the total shown
each time enter is pressed up to five times!

The total is 0.0
The total is twelve!
The dice will be rolled and the total shown
each time enter is pressed up to five times!

The total is 0.0
The total is six!
The dice will be rolled and the total shown
each time enter is pressed up to five times!

The total is 0.0
The total is twelve!
The dice will be rolled and the total shown
each time enter is pressed up to five times!

The total is 0.0
```

Comment: Each time you make the comparison, you’re calling `randint` again, and it’s going to return a different random value. Put the results in variables.

Comment: Your dice is rolling and rolling, becoming a ball which never stops changing current value.

Answer (score 1):

every time you call `random.randint(MIN,MAX)` you get a NEW random number.

you need to do something like this:

```
for count in range(ROLLS):
    dice = random.randint(MIN, MAX)

    if dice == 2:
            print('The total is two!')

    if dice == 3:
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your program logic, for each 'dice roll' you are making it possible to loop **without generating a value** for a roll. Thus, you are not guaranteed to get five rolls.
 Can you see that each call to `random.randint(MIN,MAX)` is generating a new random number **for each call**? In other words, within your loop `for count in range(ROLLS)` every time you execute `random.randint(MIN,MAX)` you can get different numbers, and thus exit the loop without a print statement.

For example, imagine this is the list of numbers generated randomly by your loop:
3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2

The loop would finish without a match, since you are generating a random number up to twelve times for each roll. Thus in essence, you would get, for lack of a better term, a *null roll*.

EDIT:
Also based on your MIN/MAX values, you are only generating random values from 1-6, not 1-12.

```
'# This program will simulate dice rolls 5 different
# times and add the total of each roll.

import random
MIN = 2  #You cannot roll a 1
MAX = 12
ROLLS = 5
def main():

    totalRolled = 0 # Accumulator

    for count in range(ROLLS)
        rolledValue = random.randint(MIN,MAX)
        print(rolledValue + " was rolled")

        if(rolledValue == 2):
             totalRolled =+ rolledValue
        if(rolledValue == 3):
             totalRolled += rolledValue

        #...Etc

        print("the total is" + totalRolled)
```